# Token is approved 'Not enough allowance.'

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Only the minter can transfer.

```
contract MintedToken ...
function mint(uint256 amount) isMinter public  {
        _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function send(address account, uint amount) isMinter public {
        transfer(account, amount); //this account will need to send in another contract
        emit Send(minterAddress, amount, account);
    }
```

Then I have another contract where account has the funds but need to send

```
contract SecondToken...
 function buy() 
{
        bool success = mintedToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
}
```

In the unit test

```
it("Txnfer minted tokens", async () => {
      const bal = await mintedToken.balanceOf(buyer.address); // shows balance
      const approve = await mintedToken.approve(buyer.address, 10000); //
      const allow = await mintedToken.allowance(minterAddress, buyer.address); // shows value
     
      await secondToken.connect(buyer).buy(10000); // err:  reverted with reason string 'Not enough allowance.'
    });
```

I think the problem might be the owner?

Comment: You need to give allowance to the `secondToken` contract, not the buyer. The `transferFrom()` function is being hit from the `secondToken`. So this contract will making the call to transfer. Give the allowance to it, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried `await mintedToken.allowance(minterAddress, secondToken.address);`  also tried `await mintedToken.allowance(buyer.address, secondToken.address);`  same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it("Txnfer minted tokens", async () => {
      const bal = await mintedToken.balanceOf(buyer.address); // shows balance
      const approve = await mintedToken.approve(secondToken.address, 10000); //**The balance of this contract should be bigger than this value**
      const allow = await mintedToken.allowance(buyer.address, secondToken.address); // shows value
     
      await secondToken.connect(buyer).buy(10000); // err:  reverted with reason string 'Not enough allowance.'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually got it before you posted this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).